# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql-12

I wrote the code below, but get the error

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

I don't know the source of the error , so guys can u help me , (excuse my bad english)

the code:

```
NpgsqlCommand cd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into CLIENT values (@ref_client,@type_client,@nom,@adresse,@tele,@fax)", cnx);
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ref_client", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type_client", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tele", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            cnx.Open();
            cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnx.Close();
```

Comment: To help you we would need to know the number of elements in `SelectedRows` and, assuming that was more than zero, the number in `SelectedRows[0]`.

Comment: Looks like @adresse parameter is missing. You expect it in the insert statement, but missing when fill parameters.

Comment: You should confirm the index in datagridview is not out of range.

Comment: @KyleWang can u explain more , thanks .

Comment: You first need to ensure that `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` is not null. Second, please note that the indexes of SelectedRows [index] and Cells [index] start from 0.